# "Calzón" vs. "calzoncillos"

Tags: vocabulario

Wiktionary tells me both are underwear, **calzón** for women and **calzoncillos** for men. However, when I looked up the words on Google images (something I always do with new words to get a better idea of real-life meanings), I see a mix of underwear for both genders for either words. What gives? If it's a matter of regional preference, what are those preferences?

Comment: En Chile el calzón es de mujer y el calzoncillo de hombre, tal como dice Wictionary. En el último tiempo, se hace la diferencia entre un tipo de prenda anticuado y pudorosa (calzón y calzoncillo) y otros tipos más modernos y específicos (tanga, bikini, pantaleta, bóxer, slip, zunga). Vale decir, si en una tienda ofrecen "calzones" uno esperaría que fueran para señoras mayores o niñas pequeñas.

Comment: To Rodrigo's list I would add "culotte", which actually comes from a French word. I have never heard of "zunga" before (not used in Spain), and also I think that bikini is not really underwear, but a two piece swimsuit. I agree that "calzones" sounds like something our grandparent's used to wear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spain nobody favors the use of `calzón` for feminine intimate wear. They are referred as `bragas`, aways in plural even if it is just one piece of clothing. The word `braga`, in singular, is a different piece of clothing: [a sort of scarf](https://www.google.com/search?q=braga+bufanda&espv=2&biw=1277&bih=600&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=pNZ1VLbPHM7bsASPm4KgDg&ved=0CB0QsAQ).

To refer to men underwear people usually use `calzoncillos`. I think that, on rare occasions, you could hear "calzones", but not `calzón` to refer to men's underwear. Younger people will also favor the use of `slip` o `gayumbos`(for boxer type. [See and example](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=gayumbos)) depending on their shape to designate men's underwear, besides 'calzoncillos`.

Comment: A mi "bragas" me suena a Sancho Panza...

Comment: @Rodrigo, a mi "calzón". Quizá "calzones" también. Parecen palabras de otra época.

Comment: @Rodrigo, where are you from and what's the word preferred in your country?

Comment: @AmitSchandillia: My comment is the third in your question. In summary, in Chile it is like what it says Wictionary. But there is a difference of type: 'calzones' and 'calzoncillos' are larger and less elegant than other types

Comment: Ahh, sorry for the redundant question and thanks for clarifying. The comment wasn't there when I asked you about your country.

Comment: To me, the word _bragas_ only reminds me the image of bikini or female underpants...for focus of the reply, let's say that if I listen someone saying in any context the word _bragas_, I'll try to correct him/her saying:
Do you mean _¿ropa interior?_

Answer (score 4):

In Colombia, I only had referenced **(calzón)** for female underpants that it covers intimate and buttocks areas, extending until the half of her stomach *is like a big calzoncillo*, while **(calzoncillos)** are underpants for men that cover genital and buttocks areas, limiting to waist.

Comment: +1, I like your definition of calzoncillos, because it explains what they are regardless the type (slip or boxer) and excludes tangas, that nobody would designate as "calzoncillos" in Spain. Very accurate.

Answer (score 1):

In Chile "calzón" is for women and "calzoncillo" for men, as Wictionary says.

In recent times, it is there "calzones/calzoncillos" are used to refer to a type of outdated  clothing, unlike other more modern and specific types (tanga, bikini, pantaleta, boxer, slip, zunga).

That is, if a store offer "calzones" one would expect them to be for old ladies and little girls.

However, as general concepts anyone understood that a "pantaleta" is a type of "calzón".